# Valgrind + gdb to detect leak in multithreading process

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-leaks, gdb, valgrind

I have a running program that allocates memory in a linear way in time, causing Linux to invoke the OOM killer. I followed [this guide](https://www.responsive.se/thomas/2013/09/20/debugging-memory-leaks-with-valgrind-and-gdb/) trying to spot the part of the program where this memory is allocated. I successfully performed all the operations: start with Valgrind, attach with gdb, add breakpoints and inspect the current state with `monitor leak_check` .
Running the program only with Valgrind and terminating it gracefully, the report contains only 12 bytes definitely lost, so I can guess that when it exits it cleans the allocated memory properly.
I then run `monitor leak_chek` at every breakpoint, trying to split the code in segment to see where the memory increases, and I noticed that between one breakpoint and the next, the number of *Still reachable* bytes increases a lot. So I suspect the memory is allocated between that lines, but - now the hard part - being the program multithreaded, I can't be sure the allocation occurs between that lines or in a different thread. Indeed the code between that two lines does almost nothing. Is there any way to understand on which thread to focus or any kind of separated report by thread?
Thankyou.

Comment: have you used valgrind with `--show-leak-kinds=all` to obtain details for 'still reachable' too?

Comment: thank you for the reply...no I didn't tried that. I'll check immediately

Comment: I've just in played around a little bit. In gdb you also have to type `monitor leak-checks kinds all` to get details for still reachable memory